# Solution Template Storage?

Tags: templates, installation, storage, solution, thingsboard

I would like to know that before installation, where is the Solution Template stored?
And after installing a Solution, where will it be stored?

I tried looking for information on thingsboard.io but came up empty.
I want to know this information to see if it affects my hard disk drive.

Can anyone answer this question?

Answer (score 0):

Dashboards, Assets, Devices and other that you have with solution template are just added to the existing dashboards/assets/devices that you have. It will not delete anything you have and it can be removed if you know how to differentiate those entities from yours.